# Python SQLite3 database query binding error

Tags: python, sqlite, raspberry-pi, rfid

I'm trying to query a sqlite3 database to check if a unique user id exists. How it works is the user click the Tkinter button and then inputs their `idTag` value. The command `reader.read()` is used to get the tag's value. Once the user has inputted their `idTag` the `datacheck():` function will check the *userID* column of the database to find a matching `idTag` and `userID` .

**Error Message** : `sqlite3.InterFaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type`

Note: the `idTag` and `userID` are SHA-256 hash values

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3 as sql
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
reader = SimpleMFRC522()

# Tkinter button click Command 
def chk():

    # Function that handels getting User ID 
    def tagScanner():
        # Get user id value
        idTag = reader.read()
        # If tag is scanned 
        if idTag:
            # call Database function to check returned idTag
            dataCheck(idTag)
            return idTag

    # Function handles SQLite3 Database     
    def dataCheck(idTag):
        Database = sql.connect('MedaDataBase.db')
        # cursor
        c = Database.cursor()
        # Check if the idTag maches a value in the userID column of sqlite DB
        query = 'SELECT userID FROM Users WHERE userID = ?'

        c.execute(query, (str(idTag),))
        row_returned = c.fetchall()
        if id in row_returned == idTag:
            # Found a matching row
            print('User Verified')
        else:
            print('Denied')
        Database.close()

    # Call scanning function 
    tagScanner()
```

Comment: userid iss numeric value??

Comment: please give an example of what your userid can look like

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat It will be a sha-256 hash so it will look like this 1h2bhqwe3e3t5tet52k9h677g

Comment: What does `type(idTag)` return? Try this `c.execute(query, (str(idTag),))`

Comment: @CoolCloud Okay that was a step in the right direction but its printing `Denied` now which cannot be true because it is the only object in the database. I have `idTag` set as a Text value in my SQLite database. `idTag` its self  is a random unique string of numbers and letters.

Comment: Im not sure why, but anyway use `c.fetchall()` and then index(`[0]`) inside of it and check if it has what your looking for? Also try writing a normal query and check if it returns what your looking for.

Comment: @CoolCloud Do you mean like `row_returned [0] = c.fetchall()` ? Yes I just created a sperate test file to check if everything was being stored and it looks fine. Should I show my database structure to help clarify.

Comment: @CoolCloud Nvm it worked! `c.fetchall()` is what worked

Comment: Ive added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datatype of `idTag` must be where the problem is, to get rid of it, just change your query to:

```
c.execute(query, (str(idTag),))
```

And then instead of using `c.fetchone()` use `c.fetchall()` and index onto the list and see and choose the necessary data required. Although, I dont think you need indexing because the only data in your database is the single user id, and in such a case, I would not use a database for this, rather just store this data somewhere and do the same checking.

Comment: This answer helped but I am still having some issues. Is there a way to check if `c.fetchall()` contains a value that equals `idTag`. The code now always prints "User Verified" because the `c.fetchall()` is just returning all on the data not filtering for value that equals `idTag`

Comment: I have updated the code above to reflect the changes that have been made.

Comment: I can not seem to get that to work, maybe I am implementing `c.fetchall()[0]` incorrectly?

Comment: @tibaH_lluN `c.fetchall()` is a list of tuples, so you can just index it, without seeing what it returns, its hard to say, always `print()` and see if its what you want. Also you edited your Q to ask a new Q, which is not allowed here, anyways try these out.

Comment: oops,I unedited it back to the original question. Okay will do. Thanks for the help!